# How to initialize a remember/mutableStateOf() variable from DataStore in Jetpack Compose

Tags: android-jetpack-compose

I've been following the Google Codelab for [DataStore](https://developer.android.com/codelabs/basic-android-kotlin-compose-datastore?continue=https%3A%2F%2Fdeveloper.android.com%2Fcourses%2Fpathways%2Fandroid-basics-compose-unit-6-pathway-3%23codelab-https%3A%2F%2Fdeveloper.android.com%2Fcodelabs%2Fbasic-android-kotlin-compose-datastore). My usecase is this: I have a registration form where you can enter a code in a `TextField()`. That `TextField()` should be initialized with a stored value if present and the value of the `TextField()` should be saved to DataStore when the save button is clicked.

What I don't understand is how do I initialize the `TextField()` with the data from the DataStore? Before integrating persistency I had

```
var registrationCode by remember { mutableStateOf("") }
```

in the composable. I can also successfully save the value using

```
onClick = {
    viewModel.setRegistrationCode(registrationCode)
}
```

on the save button. Now to initialize it I naively tried to change to

```
var registrationCode by remember { mutableStateOf(uiState.registrationCode) }
```

but that doesn't work as `uiState` is a `StateFlow` that first returns a defined default ("" in my case) and only then the real value that is stored in the DataStore.

My question is: how do I initialize the `var registrationCode` with the value from the DataStore?

Comment: DataStore fetches data asynchronously. You must use a default value or null until the actual data is fetched. The same applies to all data sources like databases, Rest API,  etc.

Comment: @Abhimanyu I got that, thanks. I have a default in place but my problem is in the above code using `by remember { mutableStateOf() } ` the default is loaded but `registrationCode` never gets updated with the real value once that is available. How do I get it to update once the real value is emitted?

Comment: Kindly share a [minimal-reproducible-example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)